# Updating posts 5.12 rails start guide

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am following the manual rails http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html
I get 5.12 point updating posts.
but when editing posts, returns me the following error:

```
Blog / app / views / posts / edit.html.erb: 7: syntax error, unexpected tSTRING_DEND, expecting keyword_end
'; @ output_buffer.append = form_for: post, url: post_path (@ post.id)}, 

blog / app / views / posts / edit.html.erb: 38: syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting end-of-input
```

This is the code:

```
<%= link_to 'Back', posts_path %>

  <%= form_for :post, url: post_path(@post.id) },

  method: :patch do |f| %>

    <% if @post.errors.any? %>
    <div id="errorExplanation">
```

The mistake is to access the page "edit". Returns a message expecting a in line 7, but that line is copied exactly. At the end of the line appears indicating that comma is not over.

Any idea?

Comment: Yeah I remember this - it's wrong in the tutorial I seem to remember! A rogue bracket

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You added an open curly bracket, and separated the `form_for` onto two lines, which are both likely causing the issues. Try this:

```
<%= link_to 'Back', posts_path %>

<%= form_for :post, url: post_path(@post.id), method: :patch do |f| %>
    <% if @post.errors.any? %>
        <div id="errorExplanation">
    <% end %>
```

Comment: yes, it was those. thankyou very much. It solved the problem thx.